# Beautiful Soup is inserting random tags at arbitrary locations

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Here is the example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> soup = BS('<p><a class="glossary-anchor" name="AB_testing"></a><h2 class="hide-from-toc" data-text=" A/B testing" id="ab-testing"> A/B testing</h2></p>')
>>> soup
<html><head></head><body><p><a class="glossary-anchor" name="AB_testing"></a></p><h2 class="hide-from-toc" data-text=" A/B testing" id="ab-testing"> A/B testing</h2><p></p></body></html>
>>>
```

If you look carefully, after the first `</a>` close there is a newly added `</p>` tag. Also at the end it defined its very own p tag with no text.

I tried defining my own html, head and body tags. This seems like very inappropriate behavior and I have no idea how or what to look up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution

The parser must have been something different.

I thought the default was 'html.parser' but when I added that explicitly to the soup builder it worked correctly.

`soup = BS('<p><a class="glossary-anchor" name="AB_testing"></a><h2 class="hide-from-toc" data-text=" A/B testing" id="ab-testing"> A/B testing</h2></p>', 'html.parser')`